# Syncing progressBar with Handler

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I link a handler with a progressBar?

```
fun start() {
    started = true
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 13000)
}


private val runnable = Runnable {
    start()
}
```

Comment: You mean updating the progressbar with an handler?

Comment: Yes @AndreaCioccarelli

Answer (score 0):

There are some other solution but I prefer this:

```
final static int TH_MESSAGE_START = 0;
final static int TH_MESSAGE_PROGRESSION = 1;
final static int TH_MESSAGE_END = 2;

final ProgressBar mProgressBar = .....

final static Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(@NonNull final Message) {
      switch (message.what) {
         case TH_MESSAGE_START:
            mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            break;
         case TH_MESSAGE_PROGRESSION:
            mProgressBar.setProgress(message.arg1);
            break;
         case TH_MESSAGE_END:
            mProgressBar.setProgress(mProgressBar.getMax());
            break;
      }
   }
};

private static boolean postToMainThread(final int what, final int arg1) {
   if (mHandler == null) return false;
   final Message cMessage = new Message();
   cMessage.what = what;
   cMessage.arg1 = arg1;
   return mHandler.sendMessage(cMessage);
}
private static boolean postToMainThread_progressBarStart() {
   return postToMainThread(TH_MESSAGE_START, 0);
}
private static boolean postToMainThread_progressBarProgress(final int progression) {
   return postToMainThread(TH_MESSAGE_PROGRESSION, progression);
}
private static postToMainThread_progressBarEnd() {
   return postToMainThread(TH_MESSAGE_END, 0);
}
```

Then from ANY THREAD you could call those postToMainThread_xxxx() methods to sync your "mProgressBar".

*(I know that two of those TH_MESSAGEs are not useful, but an user could want to do different things at Start and at the End)*