# How can i keep Bluetooth Connection in Fragment alive?

Tags: android

I have a Bluetooth implemented in a fragment to send data but, my connection fail while I'm in another fragment. How can i keep Bluetooth alive in another fragment ?

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25271928/5110595)

Comment: I tried with service but i have a lot of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493431/fragment-bluetooth-service-and-fragment-connection here

Comment: you probably are doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: There is my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493431/fragment-bluetooth-service-and-fragment-connection

Comment: but anybody answer to me

Comment: so you havew already asked this question 3 hours ago. You know that you are not allowed to re-ask the question, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment: Bluetooth Service and Fragment Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493431/fragment-bluetooth-service-and-fragment-connection)

Comment: This is different question but you said have look this. I already look but i am looking different answer old question is what is the mistake but this is different.